# How to store array in a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need some help working and new with arrays. I am trying to store a value in an email in an instance variable to be used at a later stage of my test. The email body contains the following string

> Finally, your Reference Number us **7712342** - please quote this number

So what my tests is going to do is

- visit the email page
- grab that string and store as `str_array = my Array`. And I only need the number: **7712342**

The problem i have is the email body has a whole bunch of text so not sure how to grab that particular text i need.
Once i have it then im good to carry on with my tests. but im stuck for now.

Hope to find some help with this.

Here is something i quickly wrote.

```
  element :email_form, '.form-control'
  element :go_button, '.input-group-btn'
  elements :subject, '.all_message-min_text'


  def check_email_and_store_ref
    email = "test-3@mailinator.com"
    email_body = "Finally, your Web Order Reference Number is 7754468 - please quote this in any communication with us until you receive your Subscriber Number."
    email_subject_line = find_element_by_text(self.subject.first, email_body, {:text_element => 'header', :partial_match => true})
    ref_number = email_bidy.scan(/\d+/)

    Capybara.visit 'https://www.mailinator.com/'
    email_form.set email
    go_button.click
    email_subject_line.click
    puts ref_number
    #I can now use the above ref number in another method within my class
  end
```

Comment: well, show us some code.

Comment: hi @SergioTulentsev I dont really have the code for storing a string variable. for now, i can access the email..but not quit sure how to grab the value i am looking for. once i have stored the value in the case its the number in the string, then i can move forward. but right now im stuck.

Comment: Can you include the code for everything up to the point where you're stuck?

Comment: Did you open the email file? Did you parse the email and extract the body? Or are you stuck with those things too?

Comment: I am not sure what approach to follow. i can create a method to login the email (mailinator). i guess im stuck on what approach to follow after this.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and create that method then. When you get stuck, post a specific question (along with the code you've written).

Comment: ok. here is something i quickly wrote.edited the original post

Comment: @user2240134 : now what issue you are facing?

Comment: no issue yet. i just need need to know if the above code is correct. but i will run and let you know what issues come up

Comment: There is a typo here: `email_bidy.scan`

Answer (score 1):

Use **[String#Scan](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan)**

```
> email_body = "Finally, your Reference Number us 7712342 - please quote this number"
> reference_no = email_body.scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["7712342"]
```